# Django model and field as requested by user

Tags: django, django-models

i have a lot of machines, each machine has own maintenace parameter to be checked so i want to create a machine asset management

i want to create a form for a parameter of each machine to be checked and stored them to database.

machine A

- temperature at inlet / 1 hour / number
- temperature at outlet / 1 hour / number
- vibration at inlet / 1 day / number

machine B

- material color / 3 day / multiple choice
- temperature / 1 hour / number
- noise / 1 day / number

the problem is all machine and all the paramater of checking list is defined by user. how can i make this model in django.

```
class machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class parameter(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Machine')
    listofparameterCreatedByUser = models.
```

Comment: Machine A and B are different type of machines right? And. What does the days / numbers mean?

Comment: @Ceetified_karma yes, User can add new machine, and each machine has different recorded parameter. in this post machine A and B are just example.

Comment: Okay so u also have to enter this parameters in a text box right

Comment: yes, user just enter the parameter what to be checked in maintenance in text box. But what make me confuse is, the parameter that user inputed will be a model time series in django.

Comment: And by model time series you mean multiple parameters for each machine

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand what you mean would be this

```
class Machine(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Parameter(models.Model):
        machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine,
             on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='parameter')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Then you can use modelformset to add as as many parameters and machine on same page and maybe JavaScript for a lil bit improvement

model

```
 class MachineForm(forms.ModelForm):
          class Meta:
             model = Machine
             fields = ('name', 'description')

 ParameterFormset = modelformset_factory(
       parameter,
      fields=('name', ),
      extra=5
      )
```

view

```
def add_machine(request):
    template_name = 'add_machine.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        machineform = MachineForm(request.GET or None)
        formset = 
                  ParameterFormset(queryset=Parameter.objects.none())
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        machineform = MachineModelForm(request.POST)
        formset = ParameterFormset(request.POST)
        if machineform.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
               machine = machineform.save()
               for form in formset:
                   parameter = form.save(commit=False)
                   parameter.machine = machine
                   parameter.save()
                   return redirect('')
   return render(request, template_name, {
    'machineform': machineform,
    'formset': formset,
})
```

html

```
   <form method="POST"> 
       {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% csrf_token %} 
        {{ machineform.as_p}}
       {{ formset.as_p }} 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
 </form>
```